# How can i do 'create function' in JPA

Tags: postgresql, jpa

I need create a dynamic function in JPA as following:

```
Query query = em.createNativeQuery("CREATE FUNCTION func() ...");`
```

Then i call query.getSingleResult(), and i can find the function in postgreSql, but i also get exception:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: No results were returned by the query.
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:303)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:1009)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:644)
```

So what i can do stop this exception? Maybe same exception happen when execute non-select/update/insert statement.

Answer (score 0):

try doing this:

```
em.getTransaction().begin();
query.executeUpdate();
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

EDIT 2:
According to the @figo, this won't work using JTA. Replacing `em.getTransaction().begin()` with `em.joinTransaction()` seems to do the trick.

Comment: I'm using NetBeans8.1+Glassfish4.1, and i implement ServletContextListener to create postgres function, EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistUnit"); EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

Comment: This should be cause of transaction problem, what else can i do ?

Comment: Try without begin() and commit(). Just executeUpdate()

Comment: Only executeUpdate(), i got new exception : No externally managed transaction is currently active for this thread.

Comment: When i add   @PersistenceContext(unitName = "persistUnit") private EntityManager em;  in my ServletContextListener implement class, and new exception happen:    javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: executeUpdate is not supported for a Query object obtained through non-transactional access of a container-managed transactional EntityManager
 at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.QueryWrapper.executeUpdate(QueryWrapper.java:114)

Comment: You need to figure out how to get a transaction from the container since you're using container-managed transactions

Comment: I add annotations @Resource private UserTransaction utx / @PersistenceContext(unitName = "persistUnit") private EntityManager em; but both donot work :(

Comment: annotate the method that runs the query with \@UserTransaction. Leave the \@PersistenContext annotation in the EntityManager

Comment: I add em.joinTransaction();  to avoid exception: Cannot call methods requiring a transaction if the EntityManager has not been joined to the current transaction. That's ok. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I modify my ServletContextListener implemention class as following:

```
public class SomeListener implements ServletContextListener {

    @Resource
    UserTransaction utx;

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "persistUnit")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        utx.begin();

        // It's important to fix 
        // 'the EntityManager has not been joined to the current transaction.'
        em.joinTransaction(); 

        Query query = em.createNativeQuery("CREATE FUNCTION func() ...");
        query.executeUpdate();

        utx.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
    }
}
```

This can work.